# Windsor Fluent Registration - All types in an assembly

Tags: castle-windsor, registration, fluent

I wanted to use the fluent interface in Castle Windsor. Since this isn't available in the "release" binaries for .NET 2.0 I compiled from trunk, which is reported to be fairly stable. I compiled just:

- Castle.Core.dll
- Castle.DynamicProxy.dll
- Castle.MicroKernel.dll
- Castle.Windsor.dll

This should be all that is necessary for what I need it for but things aren't working as expected. I have an assembly collection which I iterate through and attempt to load all types contained within each assembly using the following code:

```
var container= new WindsorContainer();
foreach (var assembly in _assemblies)
{
    container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssembly(assembly));
}
```

I stepped through the code with a debugger. `_assemblies` has 2 assemblies in it. Each assembly has numerous types defined in it. The loop iterates twice without error but when it completes `container` is still empty.

Update:
A little clarification. The latest binaries do have the fluent interface, however they target the .NET 3.5 framework. I am working with .NET 2.0. The latest binary release to support .NET 2.0 was RC3.

Comment: The fluent API is available in the binaries. I'm using it and I never compiled Windsor.

Comment: @Kenneth: see http://using.castleproject.org/display/IoC/Fluent+Registration+API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Register(AllTypes`... syntax is only the start - you have to tell Windsor what it is that you want to register.

For example to get all Controllers:

```
container.Register(AllTypes
         .FromAssemblyContaining(representativeControllerType)
         .BasedOn<Controller>()
         .Configure(reg => reg
             .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest));
```

Here's another example that registers by following the convention that all classes whose name ends in 'Service' should be registered:

```
container.Register(AllTypes
        .FromAssemblyContaining<ConfigurationService>()
        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        .WithService.FirstInterface()
        .Configure(reg => reg.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest));
```

If you truly want to register *all* types, you could write a Where clause that always returns true.

By default, [Windsor doesn't auto-resolve concrete types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955579/can-castle-windsor-do-automatic-resolution-of-concrete-types).

For more information about fluent registration API [read the documentation](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Fluent-Registration-API.ashx).