# Registering view with castle.windsor for Prism navigation

Tags: navigation, prism

I'm using castle.windsor 3.1 in a WPF application with Prism 4.1. I want to use the Prism navigation framework. This requires that views are registered with the container "as object". I'm struggling to find the syntax for it. The Prism examples tend to show the unity syntax. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Thie 2nd answer here has what looks to be a possible example of registration:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447193/resolving-classes-without-registering-them-using-castle-windsor

Comment: for the love of god why on earth are you using Prism 4.1? do yourself a favor ditch castle.windsor and update to Prism 7.2. Prism 4.1 is no longer supported